# Eloquent return array of stdClass objects?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

Is there a built in way to return an array of standard class objects from an eloquent model instead of an eloquent collection? For example one could do:

```
return json_decode(json_encode(\App\User::where('status', 'active')
                ->get()->toArray()));
```

However this seems like unnecessary overhead since we would be converting the response to an eloquent collection, then to an array, then json encoding that array and then json decoding that string...

The reason I am after this functionality is because I am in the process of breaking apart a large enterprise application that was originally created with all business logic within controller methods (which is proving difficult to maintain). I am imposing a standard within the project that all access to the database (using eloquent models and query builder) must be performed in the service class of that particular entity, and that data returned from service classes should be of primitive php types so that if the decision ever comes down to replace eloquent with another orm or swap mysql out completely, these service classes are the only thing that would need to be rewritten to do so (kind of like a repository pattern, but not really since the service classes contain business logic as well as database access via model classes)

I suppose one solution to this could be to extend the base eloquent class to contain a method such as `toObj()` (probably not the best name...good thing I'm not on the standards committee ;) )

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try to drop down to the `Query\Builder` instance on the `Eloquent\Builder` and get the records before models are hydrated.

```
\App\User::where('status', 'active')->getQuery()->get();
```

This returns the result that has been built up so far using `Query\Builder@get` directly, which returns a collection of `stdClass` objects, instead of `Eloquent\Builder@get` which will end up calling `Query\Builder@get` anyway to hydrate model instances.

You would have to check to make sure what is being called in `Eloquent\Builder@get` isn't needed for the particular query you are doing.
example: Global scopes `App\User::...->applyScopes()->getQuery()->get()`

Comment: Throw `->toArray()` after `get()` and this is exactly what I'm after!

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```
DB::table("user")->where("status", "active")->get()->toArray();
```

Using `DB::table("user")` instead of `User::` will return a `Collection` of `stdClass` objects instead of a `Collection` of `User` models. (or single, depends on closure, `->get()` vs `->first()`)

Just keep in mind you'll lose access to any relationships or functions as defined on the `User` model.

I should add that

```
return json_decode(json_encode(\App\User::where('status', 'active')->get()->toArray()));
```

Could probably be converted to

```
$records = \App\User::where('status', 'active')->get()
return response()->json($records);
```

Comment: I see. This could be a solution for some instances, but we do currently have code taking advantage of model relationships (from controllers not views) for example something like `\App\User::find(2)->organizations()->get()`. :/

Comment: In that case, you'd change the query to `DB::table("organizations")->where("user_id", 2)->get();` (or use a `->join()`, etc etc.) There's options to handle that.

Comment: Would your last example not return a json string whereas I'm after an array of plain old php objects? Or am I confused? (likely the case)

Comment: Oh yeah, sorry, it would return a `JSON` string, so you'd just wrap it in the `response()...` in a `json_decode()`. I added the edit since there's likely some interaction with the models when returning a JSON response vs just straight `json_encode`ing it.

Comment: There's a `toJson()` method on the main `Model` class, but unfortunately its also followed `toArray()` before converting to json